Stored Procedure Returning Null in MyBatis with Spring Boot Integration
I'm encountering an issue where a stored procedure returns null when called through MyBatis in a Spring Boot application, despite working correctly in isolation. I'm seeking help to resolve this discrepancy.
I'm working on a Spring Boot project where I need to call an Oracle stored procedure using MyBatis. The procedure works perfectly when tested directly through SQL Developer, but it returns null when called from the application.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test (
    p_id IN VARCHAR2,
    p_output OUT VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
    -- Sample logic: returning a static string for simplicity
    p_output := 'Sample TEST';
END;
/

MyBatis Mapper Configuration:
Here’s how I’ve set up my MyBatis mapper interface:
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Options;
import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.StatementType;

import java.util.Map;

@Mapper
public interface ProcedureMapper {

    @Select("{ CALL proc_test(#{id, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{output, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR}) }")
    @Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
    void callProcedure(@Param("id") String id, @Param("output") Map<String, Object> output);
}

Service Layer:
Here's the service layer that calls the procedure:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
public class ProcedureService {

    @Autowired
    private ProcedureMapper procedureMapper;

    public String callProcedure(String id) {
        Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        procedureMapper.callProcedure(id, resultMap);
        return (String) resultMap.get("output");
    }
}

Controller:
My REST controller for invoking the service:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ProcedureController {

    @Autowired
    private ProcedureService procedureService;

    @GetMapping("/callProcedure")
    public String callProcedure(@RequestParam String id) {
        return procedureService.callProcedure(id);
    }
}

Here’s what I have tried so far:

Ensured that the input parameter id is correctly passed from the API.

Verified that the procedure works as expected when called directly from SQL Developer.

Checked MyBatis and Spring Boot configurations.

Added logging to confirm that the id is correctly passed to the procedure.


Questions:

Why is the Result Map empty and the API result null when the stored procedure works fine in isolation?

Is there a configuration or setup step I might be missing for MyBatis or Spring Boot?

Are there any known issues with handling OUT parameters from Oracle procedures in MyBatis?



This is how it's usually done. ProcedureMapper#callProcedure should take one argument Map<String, Object> (without @Param). You put the IN param (id) in the HashMap and pass it when calling the callProcedure. MyBatis puts the OUT param (output) into the map. So, the same map is used for both IN and OUT parameters.

Yeah, that's exactly what I did, and it worked perfectly. I thought using @param out was useful, but the more the code was optimized, the more efficient it was. I appreciate your help, Brian, thanks
